# Which time interval is this question referring to?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

**Question**: The acceleration due to gravity on another planet is $25 \text{ m/s}^2$. A ball is projected vertically upward with a velocity of $75 \text{ m/s}$ from a platform 100 m above the surface, how long does it take to reach the surface? My answer is 13.1s.

**Problem:** Do they want me to calculate the time for

- a. the whole scenario
- b. the time interval between the peak verticle position and the surface
- c. the time interval between the platform and the surface?

[image]

**My solution:** I calculated based on option "a", and got 13.1s but the answer on my teacher note is 7.1s (option c), so my question is, which is the correct one?  My teacher or me?

sorry for bad question, I don't know how to better ask this,I'm not good at English.

Comment: Teachers make mistakes all the time! They aren’t any smarter than you, they’re just slightly older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must calculate the time for "the whole scenario", in other words, from the time the ball is thrown until it reaches the surface.

Hint:

> First calculate the time it takes until the ball reaches the highest point in the sky, and then calculate the time it takes for the ball to reach the ground.